# Black areas on textured model, that are not on the texture image?

Tags: texturing, blender-internal-render-engine

I have a model of a character, I have been texturing the clothing objects and all was fine. However, when I came to creating  texture image for the skin of the model there were weird black shadows on the arms in the texture view.

I baked the model to create the image and there isn't a black area on the texture image [See Below]
[[image][1. Image of the problem]

The bake was done using no light source only the light of the world colour and I have already checked things like normals on the model and they are fine.

[[image]][2.Normals]

Here are the normals, I think they are fine.

Can anyone have a solution for this? the texture seems fine so I'm confused with this.

thanks in advance.

Comment: are mesh normals all pointing outside?

Comment: Yes, I'd already checked that, cause that's what I'd thought the problem was too.

Comment: Could be accidental Vertex paint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Alphisto, the problem was in vertex paint, to fix it you need to **add** to the black area of the model in vertex paint.